# How to prove group generated $\langle a \rangle$ by element $a$ is normal subgroup of G iff a is the center of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem:** Let $G$ denote a group, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.
Suppose $a$ to be an element of $ G$ of order 2.

> Prove that $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff  a is
>   in the center of G.

**My Work and thoughts:**

Let's suppose $a\in G$ has order 2.
This implies $a^2=e$
Further suppose $\langle a \rangle$ is normal subgroup of $G$.
Define $N_G(H)= \{a\in G|aH a^-1\}= \langle a \rangle$ as normalizer. $(h\in H)$

NTS $aha^{-1 }= ah=ha$ because $C_G(H)=\{a\in G|ah=ha\}$.

Is this the right idea? Of course I'm starting with $P \Rightarrow Q$ direction then I'll do $Q  \Rightarrow P$. I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: In problem there exists no extra condition on $H$ ?

Comment: @HKLee No. That's all I'm given to work with.

Comment: This is exercise 14.E.2 in Pinter (for reference)

Answer (score 6):

If $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of order 2, then for all $g\in G$, either $gag^{-1}=a$ or $gag^{-1}=e$. The latter is impossible because that would imply that $a=e$. So $a$ is in the center.

Answer (score 1):

$<a>=\lbrace e,a \rbrace$. Suppose $<a>$ is normal, then $<a>$ is stable underconjugation. So for all $g \in G$, $gag^{-1} \in <a>$. So $gag^{-1}=e$ or $gag^{-1}=a$. Now, if $gag^{-1}=e$, then $ga=g$ so $a=e$, contradiction. Then $gag^{-1}=a$ so $ga=ag$. So $<a>$ is in the center.